# Unable to add authenticated shard to mongos

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to add a shard which is authenticated.  So when I try to use this command

```
mongos> sh.addShard("xxx.xxx.xxx:27018")
```

I'm getting the following error.

> ```
> {
>         "ok" : 0,
>         "errmsg" : "failed listing xxx.xxx.xxx:27018's 
>                        databases:{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"unauthorized\" }"
> }
> ```

Please share your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear on what authenticated user you are using and what all authorizations it is entitled to for your session.

I would suggest you provide following information to complete the question:

1. User you have authenticated with in mongo. i.e. user being used for starting mongo session or any db.auth(..) after that in the mongo shell.
2. db.isMaster() to confirm you are connected to appropriate mongos. i.e. in mongo shell output of following:

```
      db.isMaster()
```

1. Assigned roles for this user in admin / config database i.e. in mongo shell output of following (by replacing the user id):

```
  use admin
  db.system.users.find({user: "ReplaceYourUserIdHere"}).pretty()

  use config
  db.system.users.find({user: "ReplaceYourUserIdHere"}).pretty()
```

This should help figure out what roles you may be missing and are required for sh.addShard operation.

Some of the operations need specific privileges and sh.addShard is one of them. You can find detailed privilege / role requirements for various operations at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/ .